# Spawn URDF Joint Stiffness

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, spawn-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to spawn a URDF model in Gazebo without loading a controller for the robot.  I have found that the joints are very 'floppy' when no controller is loaded.  Is there a command in the launch file or urdf which will increase the joint stiffness if no controller is running?

-Kyle

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12965/spawn-urdf-joint-stiffness/) by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 204 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try setting the joint friction and/or damping to a very high value.

```
<joint name="joint_name" type="continuous">
    ...
    <joint_properties damping="1000.0" friction="1000.0"/>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2012-02-10**:
Yep, not a bad idea for a completely static robot model.  However I do plan on writing controllers and using the robot in sim.  Just wanted to see if there was a quick fix, much like launching joints at explicit angles with -J joint_name 0.4 etc.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-10**:
If no controllers are running, why can't the joints just be fixed?

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2012-02-10**:
I did have this previously with damping at 100 and friction at 1000, and after playing with the values from 0 up to 10^5 it still seems that there was no difference.  These properties seem to come into play with the transmission and controllers running.  Hmmm..

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-09-08**:
This post is quite old, but if possible plz reply. What if I have objects like cupboard and there doors are opening and closing w/o any apparent reason. I want ROBOT to close and open them. in that case I guess I'll not write a controller for cupboard. How to make the doors remain in one position?